# Does iMessage Attachment Size Matter to my Cell Company?

Tags: iphone

T-Mobile says I have unlimited texting in foreign countries.  Would this include any large videos or a bunch of photos I attach to an iMessage, or would those attachments count against my 5GB international data allotment?

Stated another way, if iMessages are end-to-end encrypted, how would T-Mobile know a message contains media files?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actual iMessages (with a blue background) are simply data, so they can be end-to-end encrypted by iMessage and count against your data allotment.

Texts/SMS have a green background, they are not encrypted at all.

Comment: You'd probably have to also ask the carrier if MMS counts as 'text'. It probably doesn't, it will be 'data'. I'd guess either way, sending pictures is going to eat data allowance.